# Defining Ranges for Excel in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, interop

I am using Excel interop in my VB.NET program. My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to write to Excel *and* define the Range using numbers.

Alright, so I have objects being created depending on the file that the user opens. So there could be 100 objects or there could be none. Now each object has an array of values, and these arrays contain nearly 15000 elements. So here is what I want to do but I can't figure out how to escape using the LetterNumber:LetterNumber combination.

For every object I want a new column to be occupied and for every element in the objects array I want the row to be occupied. I figured the easiest way to do this was using a for loop but, again, I can't use numbers.

```
For columns = 0 to NumberOfObjects
   For rows = 0 to NumberInArray
          Cell(rows , columns).Value = myObjectsCollection(column).Array(rows)
   Next
Next
```

Comment: I think Cell(0,0) should be Cell(columns,rows) in that example which could be the solution to your problem.

Comment: Sorry! That is how I have been doing it but it still doesn't work. I do not use (0,0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And now I feel stupid. The reason this wasn't working was that the value of the index doesn't start at 0. This was simply fixed by starting the index at 1. DUH! I finally found an article from Microsoft that had good examples on how to automate Excel.

[Excel Automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301982)